# Why WCF's autogenerated proxies have sync method?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

I implemented async WCF service `MyServiceAsync`. In the client when I add `Service Reference` it still generates the sync (normal) version of this function. It doesn't even return the Task and the name is `MyService`. Am I missing something?

I had sync version before, I recently changed to async. Are those leftovers from my previous service or does VS auto generate both sync and async?

And the follow up question, if so.. can I prevent from generating sync version?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They way or technology the server is implemented in has no influence in the client. Or the contract (WSDL in this case).

I assume you're exposing the service over HTTP. The fact that you have an async implementation does not change the HTTP protocol.

Comment: No, it's tcpip WCF. I create async service and that's it for the server. Then.. on the WPF client I click "Add service references" and VS autogenerates the client. This client has two methods: sync and async. I guess VS allows to sync call the async service. Is that correcT?

Comment: And you expect that implementing a service operation as an asynchronous method changes the WSDL (from which the client is generated) and tcpip?

Comment: @PauloMorgado - TCP/IP **IS** http.  Or more accurately, Http uses TCP/IP.